# What is the syntax for using numeric variables in an INSERT using VBA for Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am really very new to VBA and I have been trying to insert the value from a numeric and date variable into a table using VBA.  Here is the code that I have been using:

`DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_results ( [results_student_id], [results_test_date], [results_score]) VALUES ('  "& st_student_id &"  ', ' "& St_test_id &"  ', '  "& St_score & " ')"`

Where st_student_id and st_score are numeric and st_test_id is a date...

Answer (score 1):

Create and test this parameter query in the Access query designer.

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_results
(results_student_id, results_test_date, results_score)
VALUES
([pId], [pDate], [pScore])
```

When you run the query, Access will prompt you to supply values for the three parameters: *pId*; *pDate*; and *pScore*.

After you have it working in the query designer, save it as *qryAddResults*.  Then your VBA code can use that named query, supply the parameter values, and execute it.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryAddResults")
qdf.Parameters("pId") = st_student_id
qdf.Parameters("pDate") = St_test_id
qdf.Parameters("pScore") = St_score
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion to see what your SQL really looks like.  Run the following, then post the SQL you have:

```
Dim strSQL as String
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_results ( [results_student_id], [results_test_date], [results_score])
 VALUES (" & 1 & " , " & 2 & " , #" & Format(St_score, "dd\/mm\/yyyy") & "#)"
Debug.Print strSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Comment: Sorry, disregard... you fixed as I was typing with my two best fingers!

Comment: Thank you for your help,  this code seems to have solved the problem

Comment: DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_results ( [results_student_id], [results_score], [results_test_date]) VALUES (" & st_student_id & "," & st_score & ",#" & st_test_id & "#)"